# How do you format comments?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

On several occasions, I have needed to put multiple paragraphs or a list in a comment.  So far I've been unable to make a comment on this site or even show two paragraphs.

Is there a way to format a comment other than as a single blodge of text?

Comment: Comments have very little formatting. You can use backticks to put code in a fixed-width font, but there's no line breaks or paragraphs. Long code blocks should be in the question or answer, not comments.

Comment: *So far I've been unable to make a comment on this site even show two paragrahs*. That's because you can't. Comments are not meant to hold lists or paragraphs, they are meant to be *short, quick notes for asking for clarification*, nothing more.

Comment: But if I feel I can help a person by getting more exact information out of them by using code examples in my questions then I'm forced to post it as an "answer" even though it is not an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Next to the comment box is a *help* link, when you click on it a yellow help area appears that states:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting

with a short example. The box links you to a [detailed help page for comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), which starts with:

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.

You cannot use paragraphs or lists. Code is limited to inline sections (using backticks).

This is by design, comments should only be used for quick feedback; asking for clarifications, pointing out problems. Nothing more; the real content should be in the question and in the answers.

Not for nothing does the comment box use the placeholder:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

If you find that your comment is running into one big blodge, then take that as a sign that perhaps the post itself is actually off-topic. It could be inviting discussion or is so unclear as to be unanswerable. Perhaps it should be voted to be closed instead?

Longer discussions should be taken to chat; Stack Overflow will offer to create a dedicated chat room if the  comments thread gets too long, but don't hesitate to start a chatroom for the post early (just go to the chat server, create a room, and post a comment inviting the other party or parties to join you there.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer.  The issue came up in frustration when I wanted to LIST issues with an answer.  It came up another time when I had two issues with an answer.  I ended up in both cases, just making multiple comments.